# crash when called emplace_back

Tags: tizen, tizen-native-app, tizen-emulator

I used tizen sdk 2.3.1 and run my app in the emulator. Everytime I called function emplace_back from std::vector in Release mode my app crash. If I run it in Debug mode it runs just fine.

Any idea why ?

Answer (score 0):

When you change the configuration Debug mode to Release mode, It also changes the compiler settings.So after changing to Release mode, you have to change C++ compiler to C++11 again. Go to project properties and change the compiler setting.

Check the following screenshot of Tizen Studio 1.0.2.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I used cli sdk, I don't use tizen studio. I already specify the c++ tag in flags.mk. I tried -std=c++0x, -std=c++11, -std=c++14 and nothing works. Right now, I'm waiting for my tizen phone, I hope everyting will be ok of I build it for the real phone